# Optimal control: what do I do if dH/du doesn't depend on u?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I'm solving a simple optimal problem. My objective function is:

$$J(u) = \int_{t1}^{t2}(u_{1} + u_{2})dt$$

and other equations depend on $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ linearly. So when I formed Hamiltonian and differentiated it by $u_{1}$ (and second by $u_{2}$) it turned out it depends only on costate variables $\Psi_{i}$, so I can't solve $\partial H/\partial u$ in terms of *u*.

What does it imply? Is there something wrong? How do I proceed if I can't express *u* in terms of the solved co-state variables?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the inputs, if so then you can minimize the Hamiltonian with respect to the inputs while also satisfying the constraints.

Comment: If your hamiltonian is affine w.r.t. your control input, it should end in bang-bang control. Btw, why are you taking $\partial H/\partial u$? Iirc, you should be taking $\partial H/\partial x$, no?